# Multi language website in code content structure

Tags: php, arrays

Trying to find the best way to make a multi language site. This is what i have done to this moment:

```
<?php
    if (isset($_GET['lang'])) {
        $lang = $_GET['lang'];
    }

    $content = array(
            'bg' => array(
                'word1' => 'Начало',
                'word2' => 'Тест'
            ),


            'en' => array(
                'word1' => 'Home',
                'word2' => 'Test'
            ),
        );
?>
```

And then print the content this way:

```
<?= $content[$lang]['word1'] ?>
<?= $content[$lang]['word2'] ?>
```

[Here is picture of the code too.](https://puu.sh/tm2rb/285d14bb2e.png) I'm doing this for first time so probably I'm doing something wrong. How can I improve this structure?
Also I'm doing transalte on everything that displays on the pages, not just the content so I think puting it in the data base is wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you are doing it currently is totally fine, but I would recommend to you to seperate your translations from your code to keep the files clean.

Doing this, you could still use PHP for your translation files, but you don't have to declare the translations in every file (and maybe have them multiple times)

bg.php

```
<?php
return [
    'word1' => '...',
    'word2' => '...'
];
?>
```

and to include your translation, just write something like this

```
$content = require('translations/' . $lang . '.php');
echo $content['word1'];
```

Doing this, you should also check, that the given language is valid.

```
$valid_languages = ['bg', 'en'];
if (!in_array($lang, $valid_languages)) die('usefull message');
```

Comment: Oh this is actaully a great idea! Thanks a lot. One final question: is the word1, word2, wordN the best practise? Because it's not very clear in the code this way.

Comment: You should give them some more meaningfull names. One idea would be a simple key, an other idea would be the original string, so you would get an easy fallback, if no translation is given. But doing this makes some difficulties, if you change strings later